# Spring security First login fails, second login succeeds

Tags: spring, security, authentication

I'm using spring security and i got some awkward error.
The first time that I make an login attempt it fails and redirect to a page with error 403.
But in the next attempt, after return to page login, it succeeds! What's is going on!?

Below the important part of my xml:

`<sec:http auto-config="true" >
    <sec:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/_validate"
    authentication-failure-url="/_loginFailure" />
    <sec:http-basic/>
</sec:http>`

Unfortunately, I can't put the entire code here... some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This looks odd to me:

```
login-page="/"
default-target-url="/_validate"
```

You don't seem to be specifying a login page. Also, it seems odd that after login you would want it to redirect to a page called `_validate`.

I'm also not seeing anything in your example code relating to what is actually locked down. For instance, something like:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/thesecurebit/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
```